# Elastic Search Starts but unreachable

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I'm just starting to work with Elastic Search and followed this article [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)

This article is quite straight forward and explains how to start elastic on docker. To test, I try to do

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v=true&pretty"
```

Also, tried to just browse to http://localhost:9200 in a browser.
neither returns a response, they just hang for quite a while and nothing..

Also, ran a logstash docker that pointed to http://localhost:9200 and that exits because it doenst find elastic.

I've also tried both options in the article, i.e. single node and cluster, none seem to work or so it seems..

I'm new to elastic and not a docker expert either,
Please let me know if anyone has any idea of what's going on...

Thanks,

Comment: Can you verify how you started the container you expect to visit on port `9200` and give the commands you used, and any output that might look like an error as well?

Without any of that, this question is a guessing game

Comment: sure, I followed the steps in the linked article..so for single node I executed
`
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
`
Cannot see any errors in the terminal window here.
So I try to reach localhost:9200 but the browser keeps trying does not get a response

Answer (score 0):

This had nothing to do with docker or elastic it turns out. I was running on a proxy network and that was making the defaults URL's unreachable. They became available after I disabled the proxy.